# bootstrap.carousel: how '$next[0].offsetWidth' work in slide function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

in bootstrap/js/carousel.js, the *slide* function of Carousel has a line below:

```
$next[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
```

With this line, the transition of next slide work currently after the transition of active slide. But, without this line, the transition of next slide do not work. That make me confused.

Just want to know, how the code above make that effect. Thank you!

i paste the *slide* function below:

```
Carousel.prototype.slide = function(type, next){
  var $active = this.$element.find('.item.active');
  var $next = next || this.getItemForDirection(type, $active);
  var isCycling = this.interval;
  var direction = type == 'prev' ? 'right' : 'left'
  var that = this;

  if($next.hasClass('active')) return this.sliding = false;

  this.sliding = true;

  var relatedTarget = $next[0];

  isCycling && this.pause();

  if(this.$indicators.length){
    this.$indicators.find('.active').removeClass('active');
    var nextIndicator = $(this.$indicators.children()[this.getItemIndex($next)]);
    nextIndicator && nextIndicator.addClass('active');
  }

  var slideEvent = $.Event('carousel.slide.after', {relatedTarget: relatedTarget, direction: direction});
  if($.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('slide')){
    $next.addClass(type);
    $next[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
    $active.addClass(direction);
    $next.addClass(direction);
    $active.one($.support.transition.end, function(e){
      $next.removeClass([type, direction].join(' ')).addClass('active');
      $active.removeClass(['active', direction].join(' '));
      that.sliding = false;
      setTimeout(function(){
        that.$element.trigger(slideEvent);
      }, 0)
    })
      .emulateTransitionEnd(Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION);
  }else{
    $active.removeClass('active');
    $next.addClass('active');
    this.sliding = false;
  }

  isCycling && this.cycle();
};
```